# Temporary Storage other than DB and session

Tags: php, database, web, store

I am going to create a website for my college project , My project simply is a store management system ,  I will explain what I need in a simple way , 
there are 3 views for my system .. 
and the users will enter some information , then it has to be " temporary stored " after some process the status with these info will change so it need to be store in a Database as a permanent
data ..

My question is , is there anyway to store these information temporary and also be available to all my users ? I can not find any solution because I think when I need to make it available to all users I need the server so there is no idea other than Database ! . But my teacher told me you have to store it temporary without connecting with DB  , so anyone can help me ? just give a keyword for a solution so I can google to find more , thanx !

Comment: How about a good old fasioned file? or in memory? (f.e. memcached)

Comment: xml is here for you. but this is NOT secured (in case)

Comment: memcache would be the best option i guess if u dont want to use session or cookies

Comment: @CharlesForest what does this have to do with XML? Nobody's mentioned anything about it.

Comment: @Jordan you can store data inside an XML file if you need to store it temporarly. especially if he needs to store bigger data that can't be contained inside a cookie and such. also, XML are easy to parse and store inside a DB afterward. NOTE: didn't knew about tmpfile, will check it out. thanks

Comment: @CharlesForest did you mean that the XML file will be created and then stored in the server as a temporary storage ? I mean can the XML be accessed by all users?

Comment: Are you sure you're not meant to store it using sessions? If this is for a class project and connecting to a database is out, then memcache is not an option either.

Comment: @CharlesForest you can store it in any type of file. XML is not necessarily the best format, and definitely is not a cure-all to be recommended. JSON, YAML, INI, or plain text are all valid alternatives. A format-agnostic answer is best.

Comment: If it should be accessible by all users, take a database (e.g. MySQL) not the file-system. A database can better manage things when multiple users need to access the same data. Probably it's not entirely clear for you what your teacher exactly meant what has to be done and when. E.g. a multip-step form with session management - w/o sharing the process with all users.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function called tmpfile. Not sure why they couldn't have called it tempfile, but that's PHP for you.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php

Comment: It's called `tmpfile`, because that's the standard name for that function. It's related to C, see [tmpfile(3) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpfile).

Comment: @Jordan the tmpfile creates file in"client side" , doesn't it ?

Comment: @hakre: Yup, and that's C for you. Building on a really solid function naming convention.

Comment: @user971961: no, it's all server side. PHP can't create anything client side, ever, except for cookies.

Comment: @Jordan i'm beginner with php so i'm sorry if my question seems to be stupid..I want to know how the tmpfile works ..when the user A create a file and add some data , can user B fetch this file and retrieve the data from it ? or can he add new data ?

Comment: No, user B cannot access that file. It is destroyed automatically when the script completes. If you need that to happen, you will need to store an actual file on the file system. Multiple users accessing a single file on a filesystem is asking for trouble, but if this is a class assignment I suppose you'll have to oblige your professor.